# Normalizing odd data for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, normalization

I am using the kddcup99 data for some machine learning tasks (data set here: http://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup99.html). I was wondering the best way to normalize some of the data that has weird distributions? Like these:
[image]
[image]
[image: Data from the dst_host_srv_count column]

Comment: How do you want the data to look after the transformation. Mean $0$, variance $1?$ All values between $0$ and $1$ (which *is* different from the former case)?

Comment: I was thinking of using z-score (which i think is the mean 0, variance 1 method). I am new to data science so any suggestions would be helpful! There is other columns of data that follow a log distribution, so I was planning on running a log(x) normalization on that data, and then doing the z-score.